# Query optimization of Mysql stored-procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I'm working in a **RDBMS (MYSQL)** where we have approx **15 to 20** tables major tables having more than **4 lacks rows and 70 columns** in each table.while retrieving data most of the time i have to use the **left join** that results delaying in operation. We use stored procedures kindly suggest any best method to fast operation.

```
CREATE TABLE `patient_data` (
    `p_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `entry_date` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Registration Date',
    `hr_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ua_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `mrn1` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'mrn initial',
    `mrn2` INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'mrn counter',
    `title` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fname` VARBINARY(50) NOT NULL,
    `lname` VARBINARY(50) NOT NULL,
    `mname` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `suffix` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dob` VARBINARY(50) NOT NULL,
    `pat_photo` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `blood_group` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `street` VARBINARY(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `postal_code` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `drivers_license` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ss` VARBINARY(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'adhar no',
    `occupation` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `home_phone` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `work_phone` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mobile_no` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `emergency_no` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `m_status` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `emergency_contact` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sex` VARBINARY(50) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `alternate_email` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `race` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `financial` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ethnicity` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `interpreter` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `migrantseasonal` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `family_size` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `monthly_income` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `homeless` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `financial_review` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `referral_source` VARBINARY(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vfc` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `admit_flag` INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-Not Admit,1-admitted',
    `select_reason` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `delete_reason` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `relation_with_patient` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `relative_name` VARBINARY(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `referred_by` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `referred_no` VARBINARY(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `flag` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'c',
    `update_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last Updation of Date',
    `update_ua_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tpa` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `age` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `opd_no` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `duplicate_flag` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `department` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `patient_type` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `revisit` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `simul_flag` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1= duplicate(simulation)',
    `tags` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `balance_amount` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `opd_visit_counter` INT(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `patient_camera_pic` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `baby_birth_time` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `location` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aadhaar_no` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `old_uhid` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `er_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'For current er id',
    `patient_pancardno` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `district` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `religion` VARBINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vulnerable_type` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vulnerable_data` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `weight` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `insurance_type` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`),
    INDEX `hr_id` (`hr_id`),
    INDEX `u_id` (`ua_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

;
```

**This is my stored routines**

```
BEGIN
SELECT pd.p_id, er.er_id, pd.flag, pd.delete_reason, pd.select_reason,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.fname, encryptkey) AS fname,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.age, encryptkey) AS age,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.lname, encryptkey) AS lname,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.home_phone, encryptkey) AS home_phone,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.mobile_no, encryptkey) AS mobile_phone,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.relation_with_patient, encryptkey) AS relation,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.relative_name, encryptkey) AS relative_name,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.street, encryptkey) AS street,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.title, encryptkey) AS title,
       cl.city_name AS city,
       sl.state AS state,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.sex, encryptkey) AS gender,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.dob, encryptkey) AS dob,
       AES_DECRYPT(pd.email, encryptkey) AS email, pd.admit_flag, pd.entry_date, pd.mrn1,
       pd.mrn2, id.insurance_type, fcm.f_cm_name
FROM   patient_data AS pd
LEFT JOIN insurance_data AS id ON id.p_id = pd.p_id
LEFT   JOIN state_list AS sl ON sl.sl_id = AES_DECRYPT(pd.state,encryptkey)
LEFT   JOIN city_list AS cl ON cl.cl_id = AES_DECRYPT(pd.city,encryptkey)
LEFT   JOIN ehr_reg AS er ON er.p_id = pd.p_id
LEFT   JOIN facility_category_master AS fcm ON id.insurance_type = fcm.fc_m_id
WHERE  pd.hr_id = proc_hrid
AND    pd.flag <> '0'
GROUP BY pd.p_id
ORDER  BY pd.entry_date DESC, pd.p_id DESC ;
END
```

Comment: Use indexes. Beyond that, without more information, we can't really help. You can try posting some example queries here along with your database schema here, or you could do the same over at dba.stackexchange.com .

Comment: i have added the schema

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are you expecting to get from this query?  If only one, I don't see why it would be slow.

If you are getting thousands, then accept that it takes time to fetch thousands of rows.

This index *might* help:

```
INDEX(hr_id, flag, p_id)
```

Or, maybe all the `LEFT JOINs` are many:1??  That is, is there *only one* insurance, state, city, ehr, and facility for a given `p_id`?  If so, you don't need the `GROUP BY`.  This will bypass some wasted steps.

You could replace

```
sl.state AS state,
LEFT   JOIN state_list AS sl ON sl.sl_id = AES_DECRYPT(pd.state,encryptkey)
```

with

```
( SELECT state FROM state_list
       WHERE sl_id = AES_DECRYPT(pd.state,encryptkey) ) AS state,
```

I would prefer to push groups of things like city & state off into another table, using a single join rather than separate normalizations.

I can't imagine that a binary flag (eg gender) is the least bit secure.  Even `state` could probably be quickly cracked by looking at relative populations.

I suggest that you collect columns that don't need to be searched on and put them into a single `JSON` string, then encrypt that.  That would be more secure.

And isn't there something going around about the AES routines being so easily cracked that they are banned for all but trivial uses.  Your app looks more serious than that.

I'm sorry, but performance needs to take a back seat to security.  Hire a security consultant.

Comment: actually its offline app so security is not my concern but performance is